# i receive a fatal error when i am trying to connect in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

i am trying to connect to phpmyadmin in xampp but i receive the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of PhpMyAdmin\Relation::getRelationsParam() must be of the type array, null returned in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Relation.php:126 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(1177): PhpMyAdmin\Relation->getRelationsParam() #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\TwoFactor.php(53): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->initRelationParamsCache() #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin.php(347): PhpMyAdmin\TwoFactor->__construct('root') #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(269): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->checkTwoFactor() #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(15): require_once('C:\\xampp\\phpMyA...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Relation.php on line 126
```

i reinstalled the xampp but the issue still exists.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing your browser cache and remove phpMyAdmin cookies, which start with "pma".

follow these steps

Open up your phpMyAdmin in browser
Press F12 to open Developer tools
go to Application > Clear storage
Clear all Cookies and Cache
Try refreshing the page.